# Using 'repeated' inside 'repeated' data in Nanopb

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, nanopb

How to properly encode data with NanoPB when having several nested 'repeated' fields?

This is my schema:

```
message Report {

  message SensorData {
     required uint32 sensorid = 1;
     required uint32 sample = 2;
  }

  message DeviceData {
    required uint32 devid = 1;
    repeated SensorData sensor_data = 2;
  }

  required uint32 reportnum = 1;
  repeated DeviceData dev_data = 2;

}
```

I have already made a working version in which `SensorData` fields are embedded inside `DeviceData` message based on the server.c example from the NanoPB source. This way I have only one repeated field and everything works fine. However this way I have to repeat the 'devid' field for every `sensorid` and every 'sample', instead of giving it just one time and then loop through an array of `SensorData` messages. However I am struggling to encode this with NanoPB, the decoding part is in Python. Can someone give me an example how to properly encode data in this case?

Answer (score 0):

For me the simplest way to do this was by statically defining the size of the array's using a [nanopb options file](https://jpa.kapsi.fi/nanopb/docs/reference.html#proto-file-options). After that you can access each element just like an array.

```c
report.dev_data[i].devid[j] = 1234;
report.dev_data[i].sensor_data[j] = 9876;
```